# selecting cron entry using awk or grep

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I want to process cron file with the time and cron entry into different columns of DB.

```
cat root | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}'

47 * * * * string=`find somefile`; echo $string > success.txt 2> err.txt
```

It is easy to awk the first 5 placeholders of the cron using awk. But how do I select the actual cron entry?
In the above example I want to select every thing from "string" to "$string"
I do also want to select the standard and error out file paths. i.e. success.txt and err.txt

**update:**

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

The above works for the last variable, but the following does not to find the second-last.

```
awk '{print $NF-2}'
```

Comment: Hi @shantanuo, you'll need: `awk '{ print $(NF-2) }'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach to get rid of the initial fields is to use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' --complement -f1-5
```

I believe this requires the GNU version of cut, as the `--complement` flag is an extension.

I'd use awk to split the rest into fields:

```
awk '{ 
    outfile=$(NF-2)
    errfile=$NF
    for(n=NF; n>(NF-4); n--) { $n = ""}
    printf("command: %s\noutput: %s\nerror: %s\n", $0, outfile, errfile) 
}'
```

Note that this approach involves a few assumptions:

- whitespace can be standardized to single spaces
- both stdout and stderr are redirected
- no spaces are present in the names for the output and error files

Comment: Thanks. But I do also need the standard out file name > 'xxx' and error out file name 2> 'yyy'. Is there any way to find the text after the last 2> and > ?

Comment: please edit your question to show the exact output you want from your provided input. Good luck.